# Android / Firebase - get variable set in onDataChange

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to set a variable inside the onDataChange() method and then, depending of the value of this variable do different things, but it seems that my app is not waiting for the method to complete.

Here is my code :

```
@Override
public String onConfirm(final String s, final String s1)
{
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference[] ref = {database.getReference("/users/")};
    final boolean[] correct = {false};

    ref[0].addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(convertEmail(s.replaceFirst("\\s++$", ""))))
            {
                String correctPasswd = dataSnapshot.child(convertEmail(s.replaceFirst("\\s++$", ""))).child("password").getValue(String.class);
                if (correctPasswd != null && s1.matches(correctPasswd))
                    correct[0] = true;
                // THE VARIABLE IS SET RIGHT HERE
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }
    });

    //AND I WANT TO USE IT RIGHT HERE
    if (correct[0])
        return null;
    else
        return "Your email address or your password is incorrect.";
}
```

So how can I do ?

Comment: This is because `Firebase` calls are async. while the async call is executing on other thread your normal code executes without being notified.

Comment: So there isn't any solution ? :/

Comment: I suggest you should use EventBus there to track the change and perform required work.

Comment: Thanks @Harpreet I'll take a look and tell you if it works

Comment: It can be easily solved with an interface implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(convertEmail(s.replaceFirst("\\s++$", ""))))
            {
                String correctPasswd = dataSnapshot.child(convertEmail(s.replaceFirst("\\s++$", ""))).child("password").getValue(String.class);
                if (correctPasswd != null && s1.matches(correctPasswd))
                    correct[0] = true;
                // Can use Events/EventBus or can sendBroadCast() with data {correct[0]}
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I made some research and I don't see how this would help me with my problem :/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply use `correct[0]` outside the `onDataChange()` method. Because of it's asynchronous behaviour, it will always be `null`. The short answer would be a member variable, however it'll be null until the `onDataChange()` method actually assigns it (which could be never if you have no network connection). So this method is called even before you are trying to assign `correct[0] = true;`.

So in order to solve this, you need to do your logic inside `onDataChange()` method. In other words, move that `if statement` inside that method. If you want use that value outside `onDataChange()` method then please read my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).

Comment: I can't do that inside `onDataChange()` method because this variable define the return of my own method.
And I already saw your answer from the older post but it doesn't allow me to define the returned value ...

Comment: You cannot do it this way. You cannot use that variable as a return type of your method. You need to change the logic of your code because at the time your method returns that variable, it cannot assign anythig because it has not finished getting the data from the database. That's why is always `null`. What can you do outside that method, can you do also inside. Or dive into the `asynchronous` world and use the answer from my post. These two are the only ways to achieve that.